# ubuntu default sound device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

On Ubuntu 18.04, the only way I can get any sound is by typing this:

```
aplay -D plughw:0,2 something.wav
```

This proves that in principle I should have sound.  However, in practice:

1. I don't hear anything if I bring up youtube on the browser.
2. I get no sound if I go to the system settings and test the speakers.  Likewise, nothing I do in pavucontrol seems to have any effect.  alsamixer tells me "This sound device does not have any controls".
3. If I don't tell aplay I want "plughw:0,2", that is if I type simply "aplay something.wav", there's no sound and aplay prints this:
   underrun!!! (at least 6.224 ms long)

Here's what "aplay -l" says:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My system is an Intel Stick computer plugged into the HDMI port of my TV set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: aplay -D plughw:0,2 something.wav works. At least it's a good starting point. BTW, if aplay alone does not work, it simply a matter of **ALSA** default. Can you post contents of /etc/asound.conf or files found under /etc/alsa/conf.d and $HOME/.asoundrc and confirm if aplay -D plughw:0,0 and aplay -D plughw:0,1 produce sound or not.

Comment: (Cont'd). Unless otherwise specified your system will default considering device 0,0 being defaullt. Next we 'll have to consider pulseaudio settings since sound output from your browser is likely to go through that (nasty) sound server.

Answer (score -1):

Installed Ubuntu 22.04, and now I have sound.